# Disqus - more options while customizing the text of the comment count link?

Tags: localization, disqus

In several languages (eg. Polish) there are more than three grammatical cases used for number and noun, whereas Disqus support only cases "0", "1" and "more". What's the easiest way to implement correct texts of the comment count link in such languages in Disqus?

In Polish *comment*

- for 1 goes *komentarz*,
- 2-4 and those where number mod 10 is 2-4 *komentarze*,
- 0, 5-21 and those where number mod 10 is 5-9 or 0-1 *komentarzy*.

Comment: This is probably a question/feature request that should be directed to Disqus.

Comment: Can't you swap the placement so it is something like "Comments: NUMBER"?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I'd like to keep the format of original "NUMBER comment(s)"

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to join the Polish translation team and provide additional translations for the cases you're looking for.

https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466219-translating-disqus

However, if the tool itself is built with only three conditional cases, Disqus would need to add language-specific cases within "more" in the tool itself before you could associate translation strings with those numbers.

They have a community site which might be a good place to socialize your need.

https://disqus.com/home/channel/discussdisqus/